# Finding and using the id of a permalink page for non logged in users with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm modifying a micro post ruby on rails tutorial app and am running into the following problem that has me stumped:

A user has a permalink url, http://localhost:3000/users/exampleuser.  Visitors can come to this url and answer a survey poll.  The following code works if exampleuser (current_user) is logged in to their own account.  However if you come as a Visitor, who is not required to log in, I receive what looks like a Null User ID error.  All my attempts at trying to assign the correct user id have been unsuccessful even though it looks to me that the user id is not null anymore.

Here is the error I receive:

Started POST "/polls" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-24 20:28:56 -0500
  Processing by PollsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZE/KXWCnBfE8PAn1CyAM51rnQI6z2Ut1UvHavEqSkZY=", "poll"=>{"overall_grade"=>"strong", "relevance"=>"strong", "personalization"=>"strong", "design"=>"strong", "value_proposition"=>"strong", "responder_name"=>"test", "responder_email"=>"test@test.com", "comments"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Submit Grade"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 47ms

RuntimeError (Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id):
  app/controllers/polls_controller.rb:5:in `create'

Using the console I can see that the first user (exampleuser) is ok.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > User.find(1)
  User Load (13.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1
  [["id", 1]] => #<User id: 1, name: "Example User", email: "example@railstutorial.org",
  created_at: "2012-02-23 17:27:45", updated_at: "2012-02-23 17:27:45",
  encrypted_password: "418b54481fffe05051621c500d69e44fd25573145c0b12e1860...", salt: 
  "57d9f6da0f6554e92c4180a469d5a1807c4a9dd46ce47c30b45...", admin: true, username: 
  "exampleuser", permalink: "exampleuser">
```

But this logic doesn't work in my Polls controller for some reason.  Specifically I believe that the following lines in Polls Controller are the issue:

```
  user_to_grade = User.find_by_id(@user.id)
  @poll = user_to_grade.polls.build(params[:poll])
```

Any insights would be most appreciated.
John

Polls Controller

```
class PollsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    if current_user.blank?
      user_to_grade = User.find_by_id(@user.id)
      @poll = user_to_grade.polls.build(params[:poll])
    else
      @poll = current_user.polls.build(params[:poll])
    end    

    if @poll.save
      flash[:success] = "Pitch graded successfully!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end

end
```

Polls Model

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :overall_grade, :personalization, :relevance, :value_proposition, :design, :other, :responder_name, :responder_email, :comments, :next_steps

  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates :overall_grade, :presence => true

  default_scope :order => 'polls.created_at DESC'
end
```

Users Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :polls, :dependent => :destroy

  username_regex = /\A[\w\-]+\z/i
  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name,  :presence   => true,
                    :length     => { :maximum => 50 }

  validates :username,  :presence   => true,
                        :length     => { :maximum => 50 },
                        :format     => { :with => username_regex },
                        :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  validates :email, :presence   => true,
                    :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  validates :password, :presence     => true,
                       :confirmation => true,
                       :length       => { :within => 6..40 }

  before_save :encrypt_password, :create_permalink

  #Returns true if the user's password matches the submitted password
  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    #Compare stored to submitted encrypted versions
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    #handles 2 scenarios: invalid email and a successful email, password mismatch implicitly since returns nil at end of method
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return nil if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
    user = find_by_id(id)
    (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil
  end

  def to_param
    permalink
  end

  private
    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = make_salt unless has_password?(password)
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(string)
      secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
    end

    def make_salt
      secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
    end

    def secure_hash(string)
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
    end

    def create_permalink
      self.permalink = username.downcase
    end
end
```

Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update] 
  before_filter :admin_user,   :only => [:index, :destroy]

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
    @polls = @user.polls.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    @title = @user.name
    @poll = Poll.new
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      #Handle a successful save.
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Signup Success welcome to Grademypitch!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      @user.password = ""
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @title = "Edit user"
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @title = "All users"
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

  def destroy
    User.find_by_permalink(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  private
    def authenticate
      deny_access unless signed_in?
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

Pages Controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @title = "Home"
    @poll = Poll.new
  end

  def contact
    @title = "Contact"
  end

  def about
    @title = "About"
  end

  def help
    @title = "Help"
  end
end
```

Routes

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do  
  # removed when added session new/create/destroy....   get "sessions/new"

  #get "users/new" , can remove now that resources :users added cause it automatically adds all routes for users!

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :polls,    :only => [:new, :create]

  match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  :to => 'sessions#new'  
  match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

  root :to => 'pages#home'

  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, line 5 of your `PollsController` is the problem:

`user_to_grade = User.find_by_id(@user.id)`

And it doesn't look like you've defined `@user` anywhere in your `PollsController`.

Here is the relevant part:

```
if current_user.blank?
  user_to_grade = User.find_by_id(@user.id)
  @poll = user_to_grade.polls.build(params[:poll])
else
  @poll = current_user.polls.build(params[:poll])
end
```

When the user is logged in, you're building a poll on the current user. When the user isn't logged in, you're first trying to find a user with the same id as @user (nil) which fails, and then trying to build a poll on that user.

What exactly is your desired behavior for users that aren't logged in? Should they be able to hit the create action at all?

Comment: Thanks for the help James.  Yes the logged out user should be able to hit the create action.  The reason why is they are going to a permalink page to fill out a poll.  They won't be required to sign in to fill out the poll.  I actually figured out a solution using the session function which I posted.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out.

Step 1 - I installed ruby-debug which helped me determine that the @user.id was nil when it reached the polls controller.  So between the users controller and the polls controller the @user.id was being forgotten.

Step 2 - I researched that the session function as a possible solution so I modified the following areas to:

Users Controller

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
    @polls = @user.polls.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    @title = @user.name
    @poll = Poll.new

    if current_user.blank?
      session[:remember_token] = @user.id
    end
  end
```

Here I added a session token to remember the user id from the user page with the permalink - i.e. users/exampleuser.  So when I now goto the Polls controller it can call upon the session token and find out what user id we were coming from with the following code...

Polls Controller

```
    def create
        if current_user.blank?
          user_to_grade = User.find_by_id(session[:remember_token])
          @poll = user_to_grade.polls.build(params[:poll])
        else
          @poll = current_user.polls.build(params[:poll])
        end
    .
    .
    .
```

The key line is the User.find_by_id(session[:remember_token]).  This now uses the user id from the user controller and is not nil anymore which solves the issue of how to remember the user id from controller to controller!